# Browse svc file over https

Tags: asp.net, wcf, service, https, config

I have a service. I can browse it's svc file with http. But, I am unable to access it over https. Do I need to make some config changes for it?
Here's a sample config file

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>

    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>

      <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/Sum_Wcf/Service1.svc" binding="webHttpBinding"
      behaviorConfiguration="EndPointBehavior" contract="SumServiceReference.IService1" name="WebHttpBinding_Well" />
      </client>

      <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>

        <standardEndpoints>
        <webScriptEndpoint>
          <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
        </standardEndpoint>
        </webScriptEndpoint>
      </standardEndpoints>

      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="EndPointBehavior">
            <enableWebScript />
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
   </system.serviceModel>

   <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>

  </configuration>
```

This is the server side config file.
The client element is there, as it's a demo app and i have a client application in the same application also, for testing purpose.

Comment: [Google](http://www.google.com/webhp?nord=1#nord=1&q=SSL+with+WebHttpBinding) turned this up, among others: [SSL for webHttpBinding](http://taciturndiscourse.com/services/ssl-for-webhttpbinding/)

Comment: your web.config seem to be mixed with client config and server config. So is the config file used in client side or service side?

Comment: This is a server config

Answer (score 1):

WCF 4.0 introduced the concepts of default endpoints, bindings and behaviors.  Out of the box, without adding anything to the config file, you will get a default endpoint at the location of the .svc file, with a default binding of `basicHttpBinding`.  The default security mode of `basicHttpBinding` is "None", so even if everything else was configured correctly I would not expect you to be able to browse the service over SSL.

So, first, your config file.  You have defined client endpoints - you would only need those in your service config if your service was calling another service, which it doesn't appear to be.  What you need are service endpoints (you have one by default, but you want `webHttpBinding`, not `basicHttpBinding`.

Now, if you want to stick with the defaults (with overrides as necessary), you can try something like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding>
        <security mode="Transport" />
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"
                             aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  <standardEndpoints>
    <webScriptEndpoint>
      <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
    </webScriptEndpoint>
  </standardEndpoints>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <enableWebScript />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <protocolMapping>
    <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
  </protocolMapping>
```

What this does is sets up a default configuration for `webHttpBindng` (by omitting the `name` attribute on the `<binding>` element) that sets the `securityMode` to "Transport" - this means that any service using that config with a `webHttpBinding` would use your defined binding configuration.

The same applies to the behavior - the configuration specified will be used by default for endpoints because the `name` attribute is omitted.

The final section is the `<protocolMappings>` section - here you're telling the application to use `webHttpBinding` for transport `https`.

You can still explicitly define endpoints as you did in WCF 3/3.5.

I'm not sure (as I've not used SSL with WCF, or `webHttpBinding` for that matter), but you may also need a certificate to do so, but you can try the above to see if it gets you going in the right direction.

Also a take a look at the [article](http://taciturndiscourse.com/services/ssl-for-webhttpbinding/) I linked to in my comment on your question, or the link to the Google search results for additional information.

Comment: Not sure if the configuration example has typos or it's a difference in IIS, but on Server 2012 R2, IIS 8.5.9600, the `<securityMode="Transport" />` should be `<security mode="Transport" />` and `<protocolMappings>` becomes `<protocolMapping>`.

Comment: @Aaron - Typos.  Thanks for pointing them out, I've fixed them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add binding xml tag with basichttpbinding tag inside it and inside that add `<security mode="Transport"/>`

Of course you can tie up all configs using the name, below its named https:

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="https">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Re-read the OP's question...adding a `basicHttpBinding` with a securityMode of "Transport" won't help.  They're using `webHttpBinding`.

Comment: I need webHttpBinding